# give different background image to layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have xml file with linear layout with id

```
android:id="@+id/layout_id.
```

in my other java file which does not have this layout as its layout,
I have called

```
View view = MessageIndex.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_id, parent, false);
```

to set values of widgets in layout_id linear layout.

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.abc);
```

Now I would like to give two background images to this layout for two conditions.
like

```
if(a)
{
LinearLayout right=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
right.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1) );
}
else
{
LinearLayout right=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id);
right.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image2) 
}
```

But then, the app crashes when I write the above two if-else statements.

Comment: post the crash log...

Comment: please post the error message.

Comment: I figured out. Since `findviewbyid` considers the currrent view and to change the view which is not the current view,


Replace


`LinearLayout right=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id);`

To 

`LinearLayout right=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout_id);`